# centering a grow effect for a centered text

Tags: html, css, centering

Because of `transform: translateZ(0);` position of h1 changes. If I remove it, effect not working properly.

How can I change below code and have h1 centered, and grow effect happens at the center of text?

I found a grow effect from [here](https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover) but the codes has transforms that conflict with each other

```css
h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
.hvr-grow {
    transform-origin:center center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*transform: translateZ(0);*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
    transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<h1 class="hvr-grow">Hello I'm centered</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is straight forward. Both of the codes has transforms that  conflict with eachother

Comment: mad dudes I added the <>. Maybe you can now be more relax

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Read the web about the behavior of stack users.

Comment: never mind! I'm waiting for the answer. And I cannot understand the -2 even my question is clear. even after that.

Comment: so the mad is correct, for the -1. Thanks stack anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have applied two different CSS transforms to the same element: first, you have applied `translate(-50%, -50%)`, and then you apply `scale(1.8)`. The annoying thing about CSS transforms is that **they do not stack**, so basically your scaling will overwrite the translate... in other words, with your original code, the following styles will apply in the hover state:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* This will be overwritten! */
transform: scale(1.8);             /* Overwrites all preceding transforms */
```

What you can do is simply to combine them in the `:hover` selector, i.e.

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.8);
```

p/s: On a side note, since you are using the CSS transform trick to vertically center your element, you do not need to use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` tricks.

Here is a working example:

```css
h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.hvr-grow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.8);
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<h1 class="hvr-grow">Hello I'm centered</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I cannot found in hours of searching web.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the positioning of your header. As you position it absolutely, the transform is starting always 50% from the edge. In order to have text animated properly, you can make the `<h1/>` container 100% wide and then center the text inside using text centering CSS:

```css
h1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.hvr-grow {
    transform-origin:center center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*transform: translateZ(0);*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
    transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<h1 class="hvr-grow">Hello I'm centered</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What if we have not text?

Comment: Then you can position div inside properly, e.g. by giving it `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` or using `flex`, if possible (the simplest way to position any elements in modern browsers).